# Restoring a postgres database I dumped from remote

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh, psql, restore

I'm trying to dump and restore a Postgres database hosted on an AWS bastion, using psql. To do that I need to open a SSH tunnel.

I open the tunnel this way:
`ssh -v -A admin@bastion.my.company.name -L 15432:databasename.amazonaws.com:5432 -N`

Then dump it with:
`pg_dump -v -h 0.0.0.0 -p 15432 -U postgres -d databasename --clean -T tablesINeed > ~/pgdumps/databasenamedump.sql`

So far so good, I can dum through my tunnel. Then I close the tunnel and try to restore:
`psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5432 -U postgres -d databasename < ~/pgdumps/databasenamedump.sql`

But I get:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

How is that? I probably don't understand dump/restore conceptually? Once I have my dumped db, I simply want to run a local instance of it.
Am I supposed to use `15432` (the port I opened for the ssh tunnel) to restore? I'm afraid of trying as this is a production database. I tried looking on psql documentation but didn't find a similar scenario

Thank you for any clarification

Comment: Make sure local instance runs on local host; check with "show listen_addresses" and "show port" on this local instance. Can you connect to this local instance as OS user postgres just by running "psql" ?

Answer (score 1):

> Once I have my dumped db, I simply want to run a local instance of it. Am I supposed to use 15432 (the port I opened for the ssh tunnel) to restore? I'm afraid of trying as this is a production database.

You are correct to be afraid.  That would restore back to the same database you dumped from, which is not what you want to happen. Changes on production since the dump could be lost, since you had specified `--clean` to pg_dump.

pg_restore doesn't create the database instance, it just restores into an already running instance.  So you have to start by doing an `initdb` (or equivalent) to create such an instance, and `pg_ctl start` (or equivalent) to start it up.  Unless of course you have already done those things, but the error message you get suggests that you have not, or didn't do it correctly.

> I tried looking on psql documentation but didn't find a similar scenario

`psql` is just a command line "client" tool for connecting to the database, it is not the database software itself, so its documentation wouldn't be very relevant to you.

You may need to take a step back and start at the [beginning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-start.html).